# How to create two different login for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, omniauth

My current ios app backend system is build on rails. I am building a new login for public user but the current login is already linked to the admin login. Should I create a new app and share the same database or is there any other way to create 2 login within the rails app. My current admin login is build with devise and omniauth.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the same table for authentication but use authorization to configure which user is an administrator and which one is a public user

Comment: I'm actaully pretty new with rails. I asked some feedback from other place and that will seems to be creating too many "if"?